# Proposal of the Virasoro modes and algebra

Tags: string-theory, history, lie-algebra, quantum-anomalies

Hi I am wondering what the first published paper on Virasoro modes was? And what about Virasoro algebra?

Comment: One would naively guess it was by Virasoro but did you check Google Scholar and go down the citation trail to the source?

Comment: Might this question be better suited for [hsm.SE]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [dedicated SE on the history of science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) where such questions are better addressed, especially when there is no clear answer.

In that site   you'd probably get the mathematicians' narrative, so, then

- I. M. Gel'fandD. B. Fuks,
  *Functional Analysis and Its Applications* , 
  October 1968, Volume **2**, Issue 4, pp 342–343
  "The cohomologies of the lie algebra of the vector fields in a circle",
  translated from *Funktsional'nyi Analiz i Ego Prilozheniya*, Vol. **2**, No. 4, pp. 92–93, October–December, 1968.

However, you wouldn't understand much of the mathematese. Virasoro's [Wisconsin paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.1.2933) has the modes, but not the algebra,

- M. A. Virasoro, *Phys. Rev.*  **D1**, 2933 – Published 15 May 1970, "Subsidiary Conditions and Ghosts in Dual-Resonance Models".

You will first see the algebra in its modern explicit form (albeit without the center!) in

- S Fubini, G Veneziano, *Annals of Physics*  Volume **63**, Issue 1, March 1971, Pages 12-27, "Algebraic treatment of subsidiary conditions in dual resonance models"

in eqn (3.4), so in virtually the modern form. In proof (!), on p 27, they credit with J H Weis with the center, which, however, they dismiss as immaterial, as do most. Within a year, however, it is identified as useful and, indeed, crucial,

- RC Brower,  & CB Thorn,  (1971), "Eliminating spurious states from the dual resonance model",  *Nuclear Physics*  **B31** (1), 163-182 .

If you are interested in the "big moment", this is it. And by 1972, everyone is using it, cf. https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(72)90420-0 .

- P Goddard & CB Thorn, *Physics Letters*  **B 40**, Issue 2, 26 June 1972, Pages 235-238, "Compatibility of the dual Pomeron with unitarity and the absence of ghosts in the dual resonance model"

A tangled tale, and what you probably learn from it is not to ask for it...